# How to use backBehavior: 'history' on my bottomtabnaviagor

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, expo

I have a BottomTabNavigator in my Expo app as the initial page. Whenever I navigator to another screen and go back I want to have the last opened tab on the tabnavigator open. I have read that: 'backBehavior: 'history' does just that, but it doesn't work for me, it instead goes to the initialtab. This is my Tabnavigator code:

```
class MainTabNavigator extends React.Component {

const DiscoverStack = createStackNavigator(
    {
        Discover: DiscoverScreen
    },
    { backBehavior: 'history' }
);

DiscoverStack.navigationOptions = {
    tabBarLabel: 'Ontdek',
    backBehavior: 'history',
    tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
        <TabBarIcon
            focused={focused}
            name={`${focused ? 'md-bulb' : 'ios-bulb'}`}
        />
    )
};

const TodoStack = createStackNavigator(
    {
        Todo: TodoScreen
    },
    { backBehavior: 'history' }
);

TodoStack.navigationOptions = {
    tabBarLabel: 'Wat te doen',
    backBehavior: 'history',
    tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
        <TabBarIcon focused={focused} name={'md-calendar'} />
    )
};

const ShopStack = createStackNavigator(
    {
        Shop: ShopScreen
    },
    { backBehavior: 'history' }
);

ShopStack.navigationOptions = {
    tabBarLabel: 'Shop',
    backBehavior: 'history',
    tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
        <TabBarIcon focused={focused} name={'md-cart'} />
    )
};

const WinStack = createStackNavigator(
    {
        Win: WinScreen
    },
    { backBehavior: 'history' }
);

WinStack.navigationOptions = {
    tabBarLabel: 'Win',
    backBehavior: 'history',
    tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
        <Icon2
            focused={focused}
            size={26}
            style={{ marginBottom: -3 }}
            color={focused ? Colors.tabIconSelected : Colors.tabIconDefault}
            name={'ticket'}
        />
    )
};

const UserStack = createStackNavigator(
    {
        User: UserScreen
    },
    { backBehavior: 'history' }
);

UserStack.navigationOptions = {
    tabBarLabel: 'Account',
    backBehavior: 'history',
    tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
        <TabBarIcon focused={focused} name={'md-person'} />
    )
};

export default createBottomTabNavigator(
    {
        DiscoverStack,
        TodoStack,
        ShopStack,
        WinStack,
        UserStack
    },
    { backBehavior: 'history' }
);
```

Comment: I understand that this function is currently being developed after receiving feedback. Isn't it?

Comment: @hongdevelop I've read it in the documentation: [link](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/bottom-tab-navigator.html): `backBehavior - initialRoute to return to initial tab, order to return to previous tab, history to return to last visited tab, or none.` It should work when it is on the documentation page right?

Comment: See the answers below.

Answer (score 0):

Use `createAppContainer` as the code below.

instead

example.js:

```js
const defaultNavigationOptions = {
  headerTintColor: "color",
  headerStyle: {
    backgroundColor: "color"
  },
  headerTitleStyle: {
    fontWeight: "your select weight",
    fontSize: "select size"
  },
};

const DiscoverStack = createStackNavigator(
    {
        Discover: DiscoverScreen
    },
    {
    defaultNavigationOptions,
  }
);

const AppNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
   dis : DiscoverStack,
   ...
  },
 backBehavior: 'history'
);

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(AppNavigator);

export default AppContainer;
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't remember the tab history with this solution. I don't know what else it could be.

Comment: How about changing the configuration of the navigator?

Comment: i have but it didn't make a difference, could it be because when i navigate from a tab item to a sub page it isnt a stacknavigator. The tab menu also dissapears whenever i navigate to a sub page inside of a tab

Answer (score 0):

Try to downgrade `react-navigation-tabs` to `1.2.0`